# i want use fragment for login but have problem with Stringrequest

Tags: java, android, fragment

i want use fragment for create a login page but when i copy my codes from activity to fragment have problem with Stringrequest and i cant replace anything...
there is my code :

latest code in activity :

```
final ProgressDialog loader = ProgressDialog.show(this,
            "Inserting...", "please wait",
            false, false);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.register_api,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equals("a user with same information existing")) {
                        loader.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        loader.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loader.dismiss();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", edUsername.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("userphone", edUserPhone.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("useremail", edUserEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("userpassword", edUserPassword.getText().toString().trim());

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your context in fragment like : this & yourActivity.this to getContext(); or make constructor from Context class.

usually it's workign.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an answer to the question. To improve your answers, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'this' with getActivity() or context.